# Is there a php function to turn an associative array into a bunch of request parameters?

Tags: php

I have an array of the form `array( 'paramName1'=>'param1', 'paramName2'=>'param2', ...)` and want to turn it into a request string of the form `paramName1=param1&paramName2=param2&...`

It's easy enough to write a function to do this myself, but I was wondering if php already had a function to do this built in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and that is [`http_build_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). It's only available in PHP 5 though so if you're still using PHP 4 you'll have to roll your own function.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I knew there was something but couldn't find it.
Thanks.